# Fortran: modules and array size

Tags: arrays, module, fortran, fortran90

I have three pieces of code

1. Everything in the `main.f90` file

   ```
   program main
      implicit none

      integer, parameter :: N = 10
      real :: x(N), y(N), z(N)
      integer :: i

      do i = 1, N
         x(i) = i
         y(i) = 2 * i
      end do

      call sum_v(x, y, z)

      print *, x
      print *, y
      print *, z

   contains
      subroutine sum_v(x, y, z)
         implicit none

         real, intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)
         real, intent(out) :: z(:)

         integer :: nx, ny, nz

         nx = size(x, 1)
         ny = size(y, 1)
         nz = size(z, 1)

         if ((nx == ny) .AND. (nx == nz)) then
            z = x + y
         else
            print *, nx, ny, nz
         end if
      end subroutine sum_v
   end program main
   ```
2. A `main.f90` like:
   program main
   implicit none

   ```
       integer, parameter :: N = 10
       real :: x(N), y(N), z(N)
       integer :: i

       do i = 1, N
          x(i) = i
          y(i) = 2 * i
       end do

       call sum_v(x, y, z)

       print *, x
       print *, y
       print *, z
   end program main
   ```

   and a separate file `sum.f90`

   ```
   subroutine sum_v(x, y, z)
      implicit none

      real, intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)
      real, intent(out) :: z(:)

      integer :: nx, ny, nz

      nx = size(x, 1)
      ny = size(y, 1)
      nz = size(z, 1)

      if ((nx == ny) .AND. (nx == nz)) then
         z = x + y
      else
         print *, nx, ny, nz
      end if
   end subroutine sum_v
   ```
3. Finally, a `main.f90` like

   ```
   program main
      use v_sum

      implicit none

      integer, parameter :: N = 10
      real :: x(N), y(N), z(N)
      integer :: i

      do i = 1, N
          x(i) = i
          y(i) = 2 * i
      end do

      call sum_v2(x, y, z)

      print *, x
      print *, y
      print *, z
   end program main
   ```

   and a `sum.f90` like

   ```
   module v_sum
      implicit none

   contains
      subroutine sum_v(x, y, z)
          implicit none

          real, intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)
          real, intent(out) :: z(:)

          integer :: nx, ny, nz

          nx = size(x, 1)
          ny = size(y, 1)
          nz = size(z, 1)

          if ((nx == ny) .AND. (nx == nz)) then
              z = x + y
          else
              print *, nx, ny, nz
          end if
       end subroutine sum_v
   end module v_sum
   ```

In cases 1 and 3 I observe the correct behavior: a sum of vector is carried out, while in case 2, the other branch of `if` is take, that is the function is not called correctly. I compile with `gfortran` using flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and no error is given.

## three questions

1. What is going on?
2. Is there a way to make case 2 work as well without modify the function?
3. What is the correct way to proceed if one want to compile `sum.f90` as as shared library? (what to do with `.mod` files?)

Comment: Indeed: cases 1 and 3 which work have an _explicit interface_ available in the main program for the subroutine; case 2 which fails hasn't. An explicit interface is required because the array arguments are assumed shape. While the linked question doesn't go in to much detail, you can search "explicit interface" questions/answer here and get lots, and lots, more to read.